# My website always looks janky for the first little while when I first upload a change

Tags: html, css, ftp

So I recently updated my online portfolio, just a few minor changes to the design, it looked great in browsersync, then when I upload it, it looks horrible. It's like some of the CSS isn't being read. I can't figure it out. When I view it in an incognito browser, it looks just how it is supposed to - knowing that, I cleared all my cookies and data and still nothing changed. I'm new to web development, and this really boggles my mind. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Can you give the website address or than some code?

Comment: In incognito, browser cache does not work. Probably you have updated some of CSS and JS files but they are cached on your current browser. Clear your browser cache to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly be that your browser is imposing it's default-styles onto your project, or more than likely that an addon/extension is changing your browsers' ability to display your CSS. I would suggest running through your extensions and see what could be causing it, or to quickly troubleshoot, download and install another browser and leave that clean (as in no additions) and use that to test.

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers tend to locally save a version of the css so they don't have to request it from the server each time you visit the page which speeds up the load time. Try hard clearing the cache for your portfolio page then try again.
modern development tools like Chrome's web inspector can turn off caching and request the entire page from the server each time, that might help you.

Comment: A hard reload from the dev tools worked.  thank you!!